# ASP Zero :System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\log4net.config'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I have a web project which still working properly until I ve updated some packages 
then I faced a run time error with this line of code

```
    //Log4Net configuration
    AbpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer
        .AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseAbpLog4Net()
            .WithConfig(Server.MapPath("log4net.config"))
        );
```

the error message said that "Could not find file" even though the file is exist.

Any answers will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it was me, I'd figure out which package update broke it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out ,but I'm wondering if there is direct reason or another fix for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For AspNet Core, you can use `HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`

```
//Log4Net configuration
AbpBootstrapper
   .IocManager
   .IocContainer
   .AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseAbpLog4Net()
          .WithConfig(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "log4net.config")));
```

PS: You need to inject `IHostingEnvironment`

```
 private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
 {              
    _hostingEnvironment = env;
 }
```

---

Update-1 : for AspNet MVC

Take a look at the [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx)

---

Update-2 : for AspNet MVC - Use tilda for MapPath

```
Server.MapPath("~\log4net.config")
```

See https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2009/05/25/asp-net-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-cwindowssystem32inetsrv/

Comment: Thank you for your response @Alper ,It seems that IHostingEnvironment  is related to AspNetCore while I'm using ASP MVC. Do you know how to solve it in  ASP MVC?

Comment: Thank you so much @Alper, it ended up with me by copying specified file by hand.Maybe that's not true but it still work